# What is the meaning of the words on the pictures

Tags: translation

(NSFW, roll over to view)

> [image]

What is the meaning of the Chinese Language on this picture ?

Comment: I hope that this picture was taken in a mirror. It looks like another case for [HanziSmatter](http://hanzismatter.blogspot.de/).

Answer (score 1):

I hope it is not your tattoo. If it is, ask for your money back!

It is the wrong way round, a mirror image of the characters. Should be: 爱ai事shi实shi, roughly intended is "Love is a fact", but actually these words together have no meaning.

Comment: plus a vast amount of compensation ........  lol .....   meaningless phrase in mirrored characters .....

Answer (score 1):

It's a verb-object structure, the word "爱" means love as a verb, and the word "事实" means “the fact”. So the word"爱事实" means “Love the fact”

And “Love is a fact” means “爱是事实”， but there is no "是" in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

爱 means 'Love' and 事实 means facts. Together the meaning would be 'facts about love'. It's read form right to left, because i believe the one who make it follow the old writing system.
[image]

Like this one, it is read 中国城 not 城国中

Answer (score 1):

The three words are "爱(love/like)事实(fact)". This phase or sentence is not normal and it is difficult for understanding. From the flowers I doubt the picture is about a Japanese or a Korean. Therefore, for the exact meaning or the cultural background, it is better to also ask for a Japanese or Korean.